# convert nanosecond precision datetime to snowflake TIMESTAMP_NTZ format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a string datetime `"2017-01-01T20:19:47.922596536+09"`.
I would like to convert this into snowflake's DATETIME_NTZ date type (which can be found [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp-ltz-timestamp-ntz-timestamp-tz)). Simply put, `DATETIME_NTZ` is defined as

> TIMESTAMP_NTZ
> TIMESTAMP_NTZ internally stores “wallclock” time with a specified precision. All operations are performed without taking any time zone into account.
> If the output format contains a time zone, the UTC indicator (Z) is displayed.
> TIMESTAMP_NTZ is the default for TIMESTAMP.
> Aliases for TIMESTAMP_NTZ:
> TIMESTAMPNTZ
> TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE

I've tried using `numpy.datetime64` but I get the following:

```
> numpy.datetime64("2017-01-01T20:19:47.922596536+09")
numpy.datetime64('2017-01-01T11:19:47.922596536')
```

This for some reason converts the time to certain timezone.

I've also tried `pd.to_datetime`:

```
> pd.to_datetime("2017-01-01T20:19:47.922596536+09")
Timestamp('2017-01-01 20:19:47.922596536+0900', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(540)')
```

This gives me the correct value but when I try to insert the above value to snowflake db, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 252004: Failed processing pyformat-parameters: 255001: Binding data in type (timestamp) is not supported.
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks to me that when you use numpy datetime it converts the timezone based on the last "+09" part. (It subtracts the 9h to make it UTC (NTZ)). Is it not what you are trying to achieve? If not, could you please specify what would be the desired value in Snowflake for a given example.

Comment: aha i did not know that +09 was tahe timezone part. What I wanted was to drop the +09 part

Comment: Now come to think about it, I guess I shouldn't drop the +09 part since it contains timezone info wrt utc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the Snowflake side if you want by sending the string format as-is and converting to a timestamp_ntz. This single line shows two ways, one that simply strips off the time zone information, and one that converts the time zone to UTC before stripping off the time zone.

```
select try_to_timestamp_ntz('2017-01-01T20:19:47.922596536+09',
                            'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.FF9TZH') TS_NTZ
      ,convert_timezone('UTC', 
          try_to_timestamp_tz('2017-01-01T20:19:47.922596536+09',
                              'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.FF9TZH'))::timestamp_ntz UTC_TS_NTZ
;
```

Note that Snowflake UI by default only shows 3 decimal places (milliseconds) unless you specify higher precision for the output display using to_varchar() and a timestamp format string.

| TS_NTZ | UTC_TS |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 20:19:47.922596536 | 2017-01-01 11:19:47.922596536 |

Comment: Im currently using TIMESTAMP_NTZ as the datatype, and in fact, I'm using it as the primary key for the time series data. If I store it as string, would they be sorted ? Also would I be able to send a query that selects certain time period if I save datetime as string?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend storing it as a string. I was only suggesting that if you can't find a good way to convert it outside of Snowflake you can send it in the current form as a string and use these functions to convert to a timestamp_ntz there. After conversion you can truncate the table to clear out the rows or move them somewhere for future reference, etc.